# How to consume old purchase

Tags: android, angular, testing, ionic2, in-app-purchase

I got some consumable product, when I try my release, I forgot to consume the product, so I update my code and now the products I bought without consumed it are not buyable.

So I tried to get the purchase with restorePurchases and consume the products not consumed but got this error. How I can fix this? I try to clear the purchases in the google store but I still got the error.

The other products works just fine.

```
this.iap.restorePurchases().then(function (data) {
    console.log("restorePurchases ok");
    let size = data.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      this.iap.consume(data[i].productType,data[i].receipt,data[i].signature);
    }
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      console.log("erreur restorePurchases")
      console.log(err);
     });
```

( in my constructor )

```
... public iap: InAppPurchase) ...
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'iap' of undefined
at main.js:970
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5134)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:5125)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

I cannot consume the products from restorePurchases to 'convert' them from non-consumable to consumable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so it's was my fault,

I change this :

this.iap.restorePurchases().then(function (data) {
to this

this.iap.restorePurchases().then(data) => {
and now I can get my plugin ...